# FireFox Inspector :: find CSS file related to <div>

Tags: customization, themes, css, custom-background

I'm creating my new website and I would like to change the background colour. Through FireFox Inspector I nailed the CSS line that manages the colour, it's `background-color: #fff;`

[image]

I now have to change that `#fff` to `#f3f3f3` but I cannot find the right .css file. The .css files are 4:

- block-editor-style.css
- editor-style.css
- theme-help.css
- customizer-style.css

[image]

Inside those files I find several `background-color: #fff;` but none manages that header background.

Any idea what .css file manages the header background?

Comment: Chrome's inspector gives you the exact file.

Comment: In this case, it's not in a file - according to inspector - it's inline in the HTML document.

Comment: @fuxia, can you please show us how to find the .css linked to a specific command in the inspector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inspector says "inline" which indicates that the CSS is not in a separate file, but instead is inside the HTML itself, probably in a `<style>` block at line 39 ( near the top ) - search the whole page source code for `#masthead` and you will probably find it.

If you want to know how it is being added to the theme HTML, you will need to search the entire project codebase for a unique string - again `#masthead` might bring good results.

**Update:**

Added grab of the source code of your website, showing line 25 where you will find the `#masthead` CSS selector, as described by Inspector - it is much further to the right - but the scroll bar is hidden, as the css is formatted into long lines.

[image]

Comment: It's most likely dynamically generated if it's being placed inline, so it's an option in his theme or perhaps the customizer.

Answer (score -1):

In fact it was at line `1586` in the `style.css` file:

[image]

but a question remains: how to use Chrome/FireFox Inspector to find the file in which we have to edit the .css?

We were all wrong here and my question received 3 thumbs up, it means there is a general lack of knowledge around this topic. Any reply is welcome.

Comment: The answer to your question changes over time, as you make changes to the site - so a function might include inline styles or a line number might changes as stylesheets are edited. Inline means exactly that, and remember that style rules can also be repeated and overrule each other.

Comment: Thank you @QStudio but my question is: how to find out through Chrome/FireFox Inspector inspector on what .css file the line is recorded.

Comment: That's my point - the inspector usually tells the truth, you just need to learn how to read it - and in cases where you find a difference, you need to learn why - perhaps you were using customizer and it was adding inline, then once saved it was added to your theme style.css - or perhaps not - you would need to give more information about the original question to get a more accurate answer - the bigger question about Inspector usage has been answered, I think.

Comment: With the Inspector - you right click on an element and the tools tells you where it took style rules from to style the element - if you think it is wrong, you need to report a bug, if instead you accept the answer, you need to learn how to interpret the information given - that's true of any interpretive tool and why skills take time and experience to gain.

Comment: Thank you  @QStudio, as you can see I'm highlighting the line I want through Inspector. Can you please take a screenshot where you see `style.css`? Then paste it in the answer and the right reply will be yours. I have several accounts with StackOverflow and is the first time I receive `3` thumbs up for a question that was viewed only `20` times. Is a good ratio and makes me think the good answer might help more people. So please, if you can nail there the name of the file is go ahead and paste the screenshot

Comment: This might be getting off topic - good that you and others want to learn how to use Inspector, it's an invaluable UI tool. Clearly, I can't inspect your project for you, in the same state as you see it, so perhaps I can ask you to recreate the original issue and show a more complete grab, including the URL or at least to give context about where you were inspecting it - for example was it using the WP theme customizer?

Comment: You are still missing the point @QStudio. Do you know the story "don't give a fish to the man but teach him how to fish"? Here we are in the same situation, I don't need `background-color: #fff;`, go to https://www.cnn.com/ or whatever other website, open the Inspector on Chrome or FireFox, choose whatever line of code that you want.... and now tell me exactly the name of the .css file that store that line.

Comment: Sure, I know the parable. CSS and JavaScript can be debugged on production sites, but it is easier to do this before it is bundled for production - that is before it is compressed, minified or altered in some way to make it load faster, cache better etc. In the case of the CNN site, it appears they have decided to load all CSS inline - probably for performance reasons, but in their development environment - I presume - it is cleanly organised into logical files, which are easy to maintain - so, the question gets bigger again - how and when to use Inspector to debug front-end code..

Comment: The next example I checked was the BBC - here they have minified all CSS into a single line, so Inspector reports all selectors to be on line 1 of a each CSS file - again, in their development builds this will not be the same, as that is not debuggable, so it is not maintainable.. in some instances, companies will also push to production source maps ( for both css and js ) which enable the browser to map the original file and line locations from the minified production assets - we do this, as we want to keep open source, open and share the wealth with others -but some others chose not to.

Comment: My point being, that we learn that Inspector can give different results from the same sites depending on many factors, such as the environment and built status.

Comment: Last comment on this - I updated the ticket to show you how Inspector was giving the correct information, as it said the selector #masthead was on line 25 of your html document - inside an inline <style> block, as I said in my answer.